# Excel Conditional Formatting based on dates in multiple cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

This spreadsheet I am working on tracks trainings. I'm having issues with this because one training counts for itself and fills the requirement for the other. I am trying to apply conditional formatting on column G that turns the cell red if the dates in;

- Column F and G are not within 3 years
- Column G are blank
- Column F = 0 and Column G are not within 3 years

Here is my best effort at the formula

```
=OR(AND(TODAY()-$F1>1095,TODAY()-$G1>1095),$G1=0,AND($F1=0,TODAY()-$G1>1095))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let **A** be the condition that column G is not within 3 years. Let **B** be that column F is not within 3 years. Let **C** be that G is blank. Let **D** be that F is zero. Let's explain using boolean algebra:

- The first condition with AND, **BA** translates to `AND(TODAY()-$F1>1095,TODAY()-$G1>1095)`. [Both column F and G not within 3 years]. You are correct.
- The second condition **C** translates to `$G1=""`, so you are correct.
- The third condition with AND **DA** translates to `AND($F1=0,TODAY()-$G1>1095)`. You are correct.

Here is the catch, both the first and third condition contain subcondition **A**, combine the first and third conditions to make

`AND(Today()-$G1>1095, OR(Today()-$F1 > 1095, $F1 = 0))` = **A(B+D)**

We now have the slightly shorter

- `OR($G1="", AND(Today()-$G1>1095, OR(Today()-$F1 > 1095, $F1 = 0)))` = **C+A(B+D)**

But both expressions are valid. Your expression is **AB + C + AD**.

Here are some sample results, letting `TODAY() = 7/23/2019` The TRUE indicate that the values on G shold be red. The TRUE/FALSE on the left is your original one, and the TRUE/FALSE on the right is my revision.

[image: sampletable]

Comment: Your saying both formulas (mine and yours) work and do the same thing?

Comment: Yep. To simplify stuff, you have (AB) + C + (AD) where A means G not within 3 years, B means F not within 3 years, C means G is blank, and D means F is zero. We algebraically simply it to C + A(B+D). I added boolean algebra

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
=OR($G1="",AND(OR($F1=0,$F1<EDATE(TODAY(),-36)),$G1<EDATE(TODAY(),-36)))
```